# Onclick set element to relative, else set other divs as absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set an element to relative onclick. The code I have works in setting my div to relative, but I need to reset the other divs back to being positioned absolute. So far I have ...

```
<div class="case-studies">
    <section class="pagination">
        <div>one</div>
        <div>two</div>
        <div>three</div>
        <div>four</div> 
    </section>

    <div class="case-study" style="background:blue;"></div>
    <div class="case-study" style="background:green;"></div>
    <div class="case-study" style="background:orange;"></div>
    <div class="case-study" style="background:pink;"></div>
</div>
```

```
$('.pagination div:first-of-type').on('click', function() {
    $('.case-study:first-of-type').css("position", "relative"); 
});

$('.pagination div:nth-of-type(2)').on('click', function() {
    $('.case-study:nth-of-type(2)').css("position", "relative");    
});
$('.pagination div:nth-of-type(3)').on('click', function() {
    $('.case-study:nth-of-type(3)').css("position", "relative");    
});

$('.pagination div:last-of-type').on('click', function() {
    $('.case-study:last-of-type').css("position", "relative");  
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You dont need to have multiple events for each element. you can use index of clicked element to filter from `.case-study` set:

```
var $caseStudies = $('.case-study');
$('.pagination div').on('click', function() {
   $caseStudies.css("position", "absolute"); 
   $caseStudies.eq($(this).index()).css("position", "relative"); 
});
```

You can also narrow down the code to:

```
$caseStudies.css("position", "absolute").eq($(this).index()).css("position", "relative");
```

Comment: You are a genius. Thank you so much. Your solution works.

Comment: @Al-76: Glad it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla JS:

```
let section = YourSection
section.onclick = event=>{
    if (event.target.nodeName.tolowerCase() !== yourChildNodesName) return false
    Array.from(event.target.parentNode.children).forEach(node=>{
        node.style.position = node === event.target ? 'relative' : 'absolute'
    })
}
```